# nginx server use HTTP/2 protocol version by default?

Tags: nginx, http2, nginx-config

I have various nginx server and recently I note that by default response these servers responses using the HTTP/2 version of protocol.
I don't have configured the `http2` parameter in `nginx.conf`.

Is this the right behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not the default.

If you observe HTTP2 despite not configuring it in NGINX, you likely have a CDN in front of it, e.g. Cloudflare.

Comment: What you say is possible. I work with AWS, is there any method to confirm it?